# Biblatex + Xelatex does not display accents

Tags: biblatex, xetex, accents

Biblatex works fine with pdflatex, but when compiling with Xelatex, suddenly accents disappear.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[
backend=biber,
style=alphabetic,
citestyle=authoryear 
]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{temp.bib}
    @article{Beck_Johnson_2013,
        title               ={The Effect of Temperature on \textit{{Anopheles}} Mosquito Population},
        author              ={Bj{\' o}rnstad, Ottar N.},
        year                ={2013},
        journaltitle        ={PLOS ONE}
    }
\end{filecontents*}

\addbibresource{temp.bib}

\begin{document}

\cite{Beck_Johnson_2013}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

With Xelatex:
[image: No accents]

With Pdflatex:
[image: Accents]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Xe(La)TeX uses Computer Modern as default typeface.
Computer Modern does not contain real accented characters, they can be composed of several characters via macros instead.

Consequently you will note that using `\'o` in the document directly will produce "ó", but writing `ó` doesn't cut it.
By default Biber converts these macros to their corresponding Unicode characters and sends those to the `.bbl` file.
So effectively we are requesting `ó` and not `\'o` in the document even though you wrote `\'o` in the `.bib` file.

You can make Biber output the combining macros instead of the Unicode characters by compiling with the `--output-safechars` command line option.

---

I would, however, advocate a different approach. If you load [`fontspec`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/fontspec)

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
```

the default font is set to Latin Modern which contains lots of accented characters natively.
So we can just go on using `ó` in the document and it will appear in the final PDF.

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[
backend=biber,
style=alphabetic,
citestyle=authoryear 
]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{Beck_Johnson_2013,
  title         ={The Effect of Temperature on \textit{{Anopheles}} Mosquito Population},
  author        ={Bj{\'o}rnstad, Ottar N.},
  year          ={2013},
  journaltitle  ={PLOS ONE}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{Beck_Johnson_2013}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: example output]

Comment: If you are using XeLaTeX you may of course use direct Unicode input of accented characters: `author = {Bjórnstad, Ottar N.},`.

Comment: I'd like to note that this solution works for `\'`, but not for `\v`, near as I can tell.

Comment: @SimonC I still get the correct output if I use `author        ={{\v{C}}j{\'o}rnstad, Ottar N.},` in the MWE above. You font will have to contain the requested characters though.

Comment: interesting, let me be a little bit more precise. i get the correct output if i load `fontspec` and compile with `xelatex`, but not if i load `newtxtext` in lieu of `fontspec`, which is what i tend to do. hm.

Comment: @SimonC That is OK then, the answer quite clearly states that you will either have to load `fontspec` or use Biber with the `--output-safechars`. The whole point was that XeLaTeX on its own doesn't cut it.

Comment: @SimonC In my tests, a document with `newtxtext` couldn't display a `Č` if it was directly input as a UTF-8 character, only the composite `\v{C}` worked. That makes me think the font doesn't have the characters available natively and needs to use the composite version. You can get that from BIber with `--output-safechars`.