# Diacritics in Bibliography using xelatex and biber

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, xetex, biber

I use XeLaTeX to compile my documents. Now, I want to typeset diacritics both in the main document text and the bibliography. The problem is that LaTeX simply leaves out every character with a diacritic in the bibliography. Below, you find a minimal example of my problem.

Any help appreciated!

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage[authordate,backend=biber]{biblatex-chicago}
\bibliography{Literature}
\begin{document}
S\={a}\d{m}khya \autocite{bibentry}. 
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

My Literature.bib:

```
@incollection{bibentry,
author = {Keith Boone},
editor = {Milton Malone {\"{u}}{\"{a}}},
title = {S{\={a}}{\d{m}}khya},
year = {2020}
}
```

Comment: Note that if you use XeLaTeX you shouldn't load `inputenc`, use `fontspec`'s facilities instead [Frequently loaded packages: Differences between pdfLaTeX and XeLaTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2984/35864). I will have a look at your MWE shortly, but maybe [Input encoding error after upgrading from Biber 1.9 to Biber 2.1](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/251261/35864) can help you.

Comment: See also [Biblatex + Xelatex does not display accents](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/281116/35864). If you replace `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` with `\usepackage{fontspec}` everything works as it should.

Comment: Also, instead of `babel` you could load `polyglossia`, even though for Latin scripts `babel` could still work.

Comment: Is the document's language supposed to be German?

Comment: @Alenanno: Yes, it is supposed to be German

Comment: Are you OK with closing your question as a duplicate of [Biblatex + Xelatex does not display accents](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/281116/35864) or do you want an answer?

Comment: Yes, that's ok!