# Biblatex not printing umlauts

Tags: biblatex, characters

I have a bibliography entry with a german umlaut in the name. In the *.bib* file the character is correctly escaped:

```
author={B{\"o}ttcher}
```

The corresponding entry in the *.bbl* file no longer contains the escape sequence but the ASCII character `ö`:

```
\entry{Bott02a}{inproceedings}{}
  \name{author}{2}{}{%
    {{hash=471f6641bcc35e7859446a7099bd375c}{%
       family={Böttcher}
...
```

In my bibliography then the entry is printed **without** the umlaut as "Bttcher". Manually replacing the ASCII `ö` with `{\"o}` in the *.bbl* file fixes that.

What do I have to do to get the `ö` in the output?

Notes:

- I use [lualatex](/questions/tagged/lualatex) and [biber](/questions/tagged/biber)
- I use a custom bibliography style based on "standard"
- I do not use any encoding packages explicitly
- I have tried configuring [biblatex](/questions/tagged/biblatex) with `texencoding` and `safeinputenc` without success

### Edit:

Here's a minimal working example

**test.tex:**

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{test.bib}

\begin{document}
  \cite{Bott02a}
  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

**test.bib**

```
@inproceedings{Bott02a,
  title={title},
  author={B{\"o}ttcher}
}
```

Run with `lualatex test; biber test; lualatex test; open test.pdf`

### Update:

If you happen to be unlucky (like me) you'll be using mylatexformat to precompile your preamble. In that case fontspec will give you hell. Here's a trick that makes it possible to use fontspec within the preamble (taken from [Precompile header with xelatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49295/precompile-header-with-xelatex)):

```
\documentclass{...}
...
\RequirePackage{etoolbox}
\AtEndPreamble{
  \usepackage{fontspec}
}
...
\endofdump
```

Note that fontspec will not be compiled into the format and thus loading time for fontspec cannot be improve by precompilation.

Comment: Looks like you use a font that doesn't have a real "ö". You could try `biber --output-safechars`. Please provide a full MWE that shows your problem.

Comment: Are you using the package fontspec?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer No, I don't. @moewe added MWE. And hurray: `--ouput-safechars` does the trick.

Comment: See also [Biblatex + Xelatex does not display accents](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/281116/35864), [Input encoding error after upgrading from Biber 1.9 to Biber 2.1](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/251261/35864)

Comment: Well you should load \usepackage{fontspec} when using lualatex. `ö` gives no output with lualatex and OT1-encoding, this is not related to biblatex.

Comment: Using `\usepackage{fontspec}` does indeed fix the problem too (although quotes are now different). I wasn't aware that this was recommended practice for using lualatex.

Comment: Since I have no answer to accept I've flagged my question as duplicate of http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/281116/35864. I hope that's ok. Thanks for your help!