# Bibliography using BibLaTeX with English and Portuguese authors and titles

Tags: biblatex, xetex, languages

I am trying to print a bibliography using `biblatex` with English and Portuguese authors and titles, using AucTeX in emacs. But the result in Portuguese is wrong: `Lus, Simes, deciso, faa` instead of `Luís, Simões, decisão, faça`. I am using XeLaTeX with the following TeX file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[main=english,portuguese]{babel}

\begin{filecontents*}{ToRead.bib}
@book{Simões2006,
  address = {Lisboa},
  author = {Simões, Luís},
  publisher = {Routledge},
  title = {Uma decisão que se faça},
  year = {2006}
}
@book{Gilbert2007,
  address = {London},
  author = {Gilbert, John},
  publisher = {Penguin},
  title = {Give me that},
  year = {2007}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear,natbib=true]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{ToRead.bib}
\usepackage{url}
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: You should not use `inputenc` with XeLaTeX.  Instead load the `fontspec` package.  See [Using XeLaTeX instead of pdfLaTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/21736)

Comment: See also [Biblatex + Xelatex does not display accents](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/281116/35864), but this essentially amounts to what Alan Munn has already said: don't load `inputenc`, load `fontspec` instead.

Comment: It works. I found meanwhile other solution:```\usepackage{polyglossia} 
\setdefaultlanguage{english}```

Comment: Can we close your question as a duplicate, then?

Comment: Yes you can. Please do.