# Problem of compilation with XelateX (Package soul error)

Tags: xetex, tufte, soul

In a previous question (`https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/548738/special-character-oe-and-biblatex-with-xelatex`), it was proposed to modify a part of the code to solve the problem. But the new code seems to be not compatible with the block code in the preamble relative to titlepage (which comes from Tufte-book documentclass). This block code is indicated "NEW" in the MWE above. This Bock code prevents compilation with XeLateX and leads to an error message: Package  soul  Error.

```
\RequirePackage{luatex85}
\documentclass[nobib,symmetric,justified,marginals=raggedouter]{tufte-book}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{fbb}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{fancyvrb} 

\newcommand{\plainsubtitle}{}%     plain-text-only subtitle %NEW
\newcommand{\subtitle}[1]{% NEW
  \gdef\@subtitle{#1}% NEW
  \renewcommand{\plainsubtitle}{#1}% use provided plain-text title %NEW
  \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\hypersetup}}% NEW
    {}% hyperref is not loaded; do nothing% NEW
    {\hypersetup{pdftitle={\plaintitle: \plainsubtitle{}}}}% set the PDF metadata title %NEW
}
\renewcommand{\maketitlepage}[0]{% NEW
  \cleardoublepage% NEW
  {% NEW
  \ssffamily% NEW
  \begin{fullwidth}% NEW
  \fontsize{18}{20}\selectfont\par\noindent\textcolor{darkgray}{\allcaps{\thanklessauthor}}% NEW
  \vspace{11.5pc}% NEW
  %\fontsize{36}{40}\selectfont\par\noindent\textcolor{darkgray}{\allcaps{\thanklesstitle}}% NEW
  \fontsize{30}{32}\selectfont\par\noindent\textcolor{darkgray}{\allcaps{\thanklesstitle}}% NEW
  \vspace{3pc}% NEW
  \fontsize{25}{27}\selectfont\par\noindent\textcolor{darkgray}{\allcaps{\plainsubtitle}}% NEW
  \vfill% NEW
  \fontsize{14}{16}\selectfont\par\noindent\allcaps{\thanklesspublisher}% NEW
  \end{fullwidth}% NEW
  }% NEW
  \thispagestyle{empty}% NEW
  \clearpage% NEW
}% NEW
\makeatother % NEW

\title{The Title}% NEW
\subtitle{The subtitle}% NEW
\author{From me} % NEW
\publisher{Editor}% NEW

\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear-icomp]{biblatex}
\makeatletter
\newbibmacro*{adtcite}{%
  \iffieldundef{shorthand}
    {\ifthenelse{\ifciteibid\AND\NOT\iffirstonpage}
       {\usebibmacro{cite:ibid}}
       {\iffieldequals{namehash}{\cbx@lasthash}
          {\setunit{\compcitedelim}}
          {\printnames{labelname}%
           \setunit*{\printdelim{nameyeardelim}}%
           \printlabeldateextra
           \setunit*{\printdelim{nametitledelim}}%
           \savefield{namehash}{\cbx@lasthash}}%
        \usebibmacro{cite:title}}}%
    {\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}%
     \usebibmacro{cite:reinit}}%
  \setunit{\multicitedelim}}
\makeatother
\newbibmacro*{cite:title}{%
  \printtext[bibhyperref]{\printfield[citetitle]{labeltitle}}}
\DeclareCiteCommand{\fadtcite}[\mkbibfootnote]
  {\usebibmacro{cite:init}%
   \usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{adtcite}}
  {}
  {\usebibmacro{cite:postnote}}
\DeclareMultiCiteCommand{\fadtcites}[\mkbibfootnote]{\fadtcite}{\setunit{\multicitedelim}}
\DeclareAutoCiteCommand{fadt}{\fadtcite}{\fadtcites}
\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{autocite=fadt}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\newmdenv[skipabove=3.5ex plus 1ex minus .2ex,% Equal to section title spacing
  innerleftmargin=0pt,innerrightmargin=0pt,%
  innerbottommargin=0pt,innertopmargin=0pt,linewidth=0pt,innermargin=0pt,%
  outermargin=\dimexpr-\marginparwidth-\marginparsep\relax]{mdfullwidth}
\defbibenvironment{bibliography}
  {\list{}{\parsep\bibparsep}}
  {\endlist}
  {\item}
\AtEveryBibitem{\hskip-\bibhang}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@BOOK{Buchet,
  author    = {Buchet, Edmond},
  title     = {Jean-S\'{e}bastien Bach. L'\oe uvre et la vie.
               Deux si\`{e}cles d'\'{e}tudes et de t\'{e}moignages},
  year      = {1963},
  publisher = {\'{E}ditions Les Libraires Associ\'{e}s},
  place     = {Saverne},
  pagetotal = {267},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\frenchspacing% NEW

% Front matter
\frontmatter% NEW

\maketitle% NEW 

\cleardoublepage% NEW
% r.1 blank page
\blankpage% NEW

% r.3 full title page
\maketitle% NEW
\cleardoublepage% NEW
% r.1 blank page
\blankpage% NEW

\newthought{How to fix} the problem with "\oe uvre"\autocite[42]{Buchet}?

\begin{fullwidth}
\bibhang=0pt
\printbibliography
\end{fullwidth}
\end{document}
```

Thanks for your help to solve the problem.

Comment: why are you using luatex85 with xelatex? Beside this: your document already errors at the maketitle.

Comment: If I don't add this code line, XelaTeX can't compile the document

Comment: luatex85 is for lualatex. It does nothing when loaded with another engine. Are you sure that you are using xelatex?

Comment: You're right, the code of the MWE is compiled without this code line, whereas in my document it is impossible!

Comment: `\ssffamily` seems to be a typo for `\sffamily`. But fixing that does not resolve all the other errors one gets.

Comment: It seems that the real issue can be reproduced with a much smaller code example: https://gist.github.com/moewew/0f19027ba38581fdc6cd5e72a20cc29d

Comment: Tracking the problem down further leads to https://gist.github.com/moewew/f898960a2ad42838f91d98d6a35ed3ee

Comment: You can try the following fix `\renewcommand{\allcaps}[1]{\expandafter\allcapsspacing\expandafter{\MakeTextUppercase{#1}}}%
\renewcommand{\smallcaps}[1]{{\scshape\expandafter\smallcapsspacing\expandafter{\MakeTextLowercase{#1}}}}%`