# Conflicts between usepackage {inputenc} and {fontenc} by BibLateX

Tags: biblatex, input-encodings, font-encodings, tufte

In previous questions (see [Special character \oe and BiblateX with XeLateX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/548738/special-character-oe-and-biblatex-with-xelatex) and[Problem of compilation with XelateX (Package soul error)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/549201/problem-of-compilation-with-xelatex-package-soul-error), I presented my problem related to the taking into account of the special character \oe by BibLateX in a Tufte-book documentclass. Actually, I just found the root of the problem, but don't know how to fix it: the problem is solved when I delete the \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}, which conflics with \usepackage[utf8,french,latin9]{inputenc}.Unfortunately, I need to keep the inputenc package for formatting special characters for other functions (TikZ for example). How to modify the code so that BibLateX alone uses \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}?

This is my code:

```
\documentclass[nobib,twoside,symmetric,justified,marginals=raggedouter]{tufte-book}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{fbb}

\usepackage[utf8,french,latin9]{inputenc}% Required for including letters with accents
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}% Use 8-bit encoding that has 256 glyphs
\usepackage[french]{babel}%.................. Language setup
\addto\captionsfrench{\def\tablename{Tableau}}
\addto\captionsfrench{\def\figurename{Figure}}

\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear-icomp]{biblatex}
\makeatletter
\newbibmacro*{adtcite}{%
  \iffieldundef{shorthand}
    {\ifthenelse{\ifciteibid\AND\NOT\iffirstonpage}
       {\usebibmacro{cite:ibid}}
       {\iffieldequals{namehash}{\cbx@lasthash}
          {\setunit{\compcitedelim}}
          {\printnames{labelname}%
           \setunit*{\printdelim{nameyeardelim}}%
           \printlabeldateextra
           \setunit*{\printdelim{nametitledelim}}%
           \savefield{namehash}{\cbx@lasthash}}%
        \usebibmacro{cite:title}}}%
    {\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}%
     \usebibmacro{cite:reinit}}%
  \setunit{\multicitedelim}}
\makeatother
\newbibmacro*{cite:title}{%
  \printtext[bibhyperref]{\printfield[citetitle]{labeltitle}}}
\DeclareCiteCommand{\fadtcite}[\mkbibfootnote]
  {\usebibmacro{cite:init}%
   \usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{adtcite}}
  {}
  {\usebibmacro{cite:postnote}}
\DeclareMultiCiteCommand{\fadtcites}[\mkbibfootnote]{\fadtcite}{\setunit{\multicitedelim}}
\DeclareAutoCiteCommand{fadt}{\fadtcite}{\fadtcites}
\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{autocite=fadt}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\newmdenv[skipabove=3.5ex plus 1ex minus .2ex,% Equal to section title spacing
  innerleftmargin=0pt,innerrightmargin=0pt,%
  innerbottommargin=0pt,innertopmargin=0pt,linewidth=0pt,innermargin=0pt,%
  outermargin=\dimexpr-\marginparwidth-\marginparsep\relax]{mdfullwidth}
\defbibenvironment{bibliography}
  {\list{}{\parsep\bibparsep}}
  {\endlist}
  {\item}
\AtEveryBibitem{\hskip-\bibhang}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@BOOK{Buchet,
  author    = {Buchet, Edmond},
  title     = {Jean-S\'{e}bastien Bach. L'\oe uvre et la vie.
               Deux si\`{e}cles d'\'{e}tudes et de t\'{e}moignages},
  year      = {1963},
  publisher = {\'{E}ditions Les Libraires Associ\'{e}s},
  place     = {Saverne},
  pagetotal = {267},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\PassOptionsToPackage{hyphens}{url}

\begin{document}
\frenchspacing
\newthought{How to fix} the problem with "\oe uvre"\autocite[42]{Buchet}?

\begin{fullwidth}
\bibhang=0pt
\printbibliography
\end{fullwidth}
\end{document}
```

Comment: with xelatex you should neither use inputenc nor [T1]fontenc, and using inputenc with three options is senseless.

Comment: Oops, there was one extra line of code... @UlrikeFischer Even if I understand your comment, the result is different with and without these lines of code ...

Comment: Sure the result is different. T1-fontenc does harm with xelatex. Remove the lines, and if you still have problems, ask again how to correctly solve them.

Comment: Seeing your old question: you  have been already told not to use \usepackage{fbb}
 with xelatex. Remove this too.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: Yes it works, problem solved without the lines you indicate. One last question: the font of the main text has been changed and I preferred the old one. How do I know which font was in use and how do I restore it? Thank you !

Comment: `\setmainfont{fbb}` probably.

Comment: The add of \setmainfont{fbb} doesn't change anything...

Comment: well it should. By default tufte-book uses pagella.

Comment: NOwadays, utf8 is the default encoding. B.t.w., can't you simply code `œ`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is solved with the following modifications:

```
\documentclass[nobib,twoside,symmetric,justified,marginals=raggedouter]{tufte-book}

\usepackage{fontspec}
%\usepackage{fbb} <= DELETED

%\usepackage[utf8,french,latin9]{inputenc}% <= DELETED
%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}% <= DELETED
\usepackage[french]{babel}%.................. Language setup
\addto\captionsfrench{\def\tablename{Tableau}}
\addto\captionsfrench{\def\figurename{Figure}}

\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear-icomp]{biblatex}
\makeatletter
\newbibmacro*{adtcite}{%
  \iffieldundef{shorthand}
    {\ifthenelse{\ifciteibid\AND\NOT\iffirstonpage}
       {\usebibmacro{cite:ibid}}
       {\iffieldequals{namehash}{\cbx@lasthash}
          {\setunit{\compcitedelim}}
          {\printnames{labelname}%
           \setunit*{\printdelim{nameyeardelim}}%
           \printlabeldateextra
           \setunit*{\printdelim{nametitledelim}}%
           \savefield{namehash}{\cbx@lasthash}}%
        \usebibmacro{cite:title}}}%
    {\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}%
     \usebibmacro{cite:reinit}}%
  \setunit{\multicitedelim}}
\makeatother
\newbibmacro*{cite:title}{%
  \printtext[bibhyperref]{\printfield[citetitle]{labeltitle}}}
\DeclareCiteCommand{\fadtcite}[\mkbibfootnote]
  {\usebibmacro{cite:init}%
   \usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{adtcite}}
  {}
  {\usebibmacro{cite:postnote}}
\DeclareMultiCiteCommand{\fadtcites}[\mkbibfootnote]{\fadtcite} 
   {\setunit{\multicitedelim}}
    \DeclareAutoCiteCommand{fadt}{\fadtcite}{\fadtcites}
    \ExecuteBibliographyOptions{autocite=fadt}
    \usepackage{mdframed}
    \newmdenv[skipabove=3.5ex plus 1ex minus .2ex,% Equal to section title spacing
      innerleftmargin=0pt,innerrightmargin=0pt,%
      innerbottommargin=0pt,innertopmargin=0pt,linewidth=0pt,innermargin=0pt,%
      outermargin=\dimexpr-\marginparwidth-\marginparsep\relax]{mdfullwidth}
    \defbibenvironment{bibliography}
  {\list{}{\parsep\bibparsep}}
  {\endlist}
  {\item}
\AtEveryBibitem{\hskip-\bibhang}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@BOOK{Buchet,
  author    = {Buchet, Edmond},
  title     = {Jean-Sébastien Bach. L'\oe uvre et la vie.
               Deux siècles d'études et de témoignages},
  year      = {1963},
  publisher = {\'{E}ditions Les Libraires Associés},
  place     = {Saverne},
  pagetotal = {267},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\PassOptionsToPackage{hyphens}{url}

\begin{document}
\frenchspacing
\newthought{How to fix} the problem with "\oe uvre"\autocite[42]{Buchet}?

\begin{fullwidth}
\bibhang=0pt
\printbibliography
\end{fullwidth}
\end{document}
```

Comment: If you wanted to keep the `fbb` font, you could have replaced `\usepackage{fbb}` with `\setmainfont{fbb}` (as indeed you did in https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/548738/35864). In any case `inputenc` and `fontenc` should definitely not be used with XeLaTeX (https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2984/35864, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/470976/35864) and `\usepackage{fbb}` is also not compatible with XeTeX/LuaTeX because it loads `fontenc` with the `T1` option.

Comment: That all said, if you use XeLaTeX it is much nicer to give the Unicode characters directly instead of their ASCII-macro version. I.e. `Jean-Sébastien Bach` instead of `Jean-S\'{e}bastien Bach` and `siècles` instead of `si\`{e}cles`.